# Color of startscreen in Windows 8 through Metro DynamicResource?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I've looked through Generic.xaml and ThemeResources.xaml in the following path:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\WinRT\Xaml\Design

However, they don't seem to contain a resource key that I can use in order to retrieve the color of the current scheme selected in the Windows 8 start screen.

The color I am trying to retrieve through a DynamicResource in the XAML is seen visually below, to demonstrate my point.

[image: The color I am trying to retrieve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API available to use the currently selected Windows theme color.

Comment: This is such a shame. I like the way Windows Phone does this way better, where the user gets to choose the theme that repeats across applications. Especially because (at the moment), apps are shit, and there is barely any consistency design-wise.

Comment: It's one way to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, no API unluckily. What about this workaround?

http://blog.quppa.net/2013/01/02/retrieving-windows-8-theme-colours/

Comment: I suppose to. Why it shouldn't?