# Get Modern UI theme colour manually

Tags: winapi, windows-8, registry

is there any way to find out the current theme color set for the Modern UI? A WinAPI function or registry value would be the best possible solution for me.

By current theme color i mean [this](http://s14.directupload.net/images/121202/ru6raz67.png).

Comment: By the way, there seem to be [no API avalible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192610/color-of-startscreen-in-windows-8-through-metro-dynamicresource) for Metro apps

Comment: No, that's not possible.  You are expected to use your own colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reverse engeneeing my system using [procmon.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), I've figured out that the registry key under the path `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent\ColorSet_Version3` seems to be the selected color.

<s>I can read and write to it using the registry editor (regedit.exe) and all changes get applied immediately.</s>

**EDIT:** After some further research, it seems to be read only, changed don't get applied "anymore". There seems to be anything at path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SystemProtectedUserData\S-1-5-21-3552576858-2522621019-3615910227-1001\AnyoneRead\Colors\ImmersiveColorIndex_Version3` but I can't manage to change the value (even with admin rights)

Comment: And this is exactly why you shouldn't delve into the registry and try and use/change undocumented values. They may not be the actual settings, and you can't always change them. "System protected user data" is called that for a reason.

Answer (score 3):

There's a private function called GetImmersiveUserColorSetPreference in UxTheme.dll. If you set the first parameter to true, it should use the value from the registry that GameScripting mentioned (and notify the system of the change).

I wrote about retrieving immersive/modern/metro colours [here](http://blog.quppa.net/2013/01/02/retrieving-windows-8-theme-colours/). Keep in mind that you won't be able to use these undocumented functions in WinRT Windows Store Apps, since they'll fail certification.